# IPS pkgrecv on RedHat

Tags: solaris, ips

Is there a way to retrieve solaris IPS packages from the Oracle repositories from a RedHat machine?

I found https://java.net/projects/ips (which seems maintained) and tried to compile it on RedHat, eventually ending up at some errors like:

```
_pspawn.c:497:21: error: ‘posix_spawn_file_actions_t’ has no member named ‘__file_attrp’
{ void * *tmp = &p->__file_attrp; (void)tmp; }
^
_pspawn.c: In function ‘_cffi_checkfld_typedef_posix_spawnattr_t’:
_pspawn.c:506:21: error: ‘posix_spawnattr_t’ has no member named ‘__spawn_attrp’
{ void * *tmp = &p->__spawn_attrp; (void)tmp; }
```

The files from that project are a bit misleading (we even have .bat files there ...). Can that actually be compiled on a non-Solaris machine or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably won't compile on a non-Solaris machine as it is, since we're using some `posix_spawn()` extensions that are likely not available elsewhere.  It shouldn't be hard to tweak that to work on Linux, though.

The `.bat` files are there from an old phase of the project, where there was a requirement for it to work on a number of operating systems (including Windows).  That's no longer a requirement, but we haven't gotten rid of all the detritus.  Patches to build on Linux, though, would be appreciated, assuming we can figure out the copyright assignment nonsense.

Comment: I'd love to take a crack at getting it to compile on Linux, but getting the time to do it would be a problem.  Anything you can add to help would make it easier. (FWIW, I have a running copy of QFS that I compiled from the source Sun released - with extended attributes.  And yes, it's nice and FAST. One of these days I'll post it to Github.)